# What does "as straightforward" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> The task would be as straightforward if you used the Arabic numerals rather than the Roman numerals.

Here, what does it mean by *as straightforward*? I think it should be replaced with *very* I mean instead of *as*. Otherwise is there any usage about *as*?

Comment: "As" implies that there is some kind of comparison. "I find Roman numerals difficult and I was thinking about using the Mayan numbering system to add this column of numbers. What do you think?" "The task would be as straightforward if you used the Arabic numerals rather than the Roman numerals."

Comment: The rest of the preceding context would help. Can you use the "Edit" button to add a paragraph or two of what came before this? That should make it clear either want the intent is, or that it's a mistake.

Comment: It means "The task would be _equally straightforward_ if you used...". "It would be _just as uncomplicated_ if..." "It would be _equally clear_ if..."

Comment: @gotube: Would the context really help? (Those upvotes of yours make me think I'm missing something!)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Right now, the phrasing seems unnatural. Something about "rather than" keeps twigging something in my brain that says either I'm not listening to a native speaker, or there's something other than Arabic and Roman numerals being compared here. I'm pretty sure it's just unnatural language, but I'm not giving an answer until I'm sure. More context would likely cure my uncertainty

Comment: @gotube Yes, actually. Looking at it again it **does** seem somehow non-native, though I don't quite know why. I think I'd probably say, "The task would be _just_ as straightforward if...", though I can't think why adding 'just' should make any difference. "_if you were to use_..." seems to help too.

Answer (score 2):

***Straightforward*** means ***easy***. Interpret the text as...

> *If you use Arabic numerals rather than Roman numerals, the task would [still] be [just] as easy.*
> (alternatively)
> *If you use Arabic numerals the task would be as easy as it is using Roman numerals.*